# Searching through a PFQueryTableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using a PFQueryTableView to search my Parse database. Everything seems to be working fine except that when i actually search the results don't make sense. For example i have three rows with the search values(truthIsName) that are "a","ab","abc","g". When i search "g" only "abc" shows up. When i search "abc", "abc" shows up. When i search "a" it seems to work correctly and "a","ab", and "abc" show up. I can give more examples if they are needed but I believe the problem is in my filter code and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
- (void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"TruthIsData"];
    [query whereKey:@"truthIsName"  containsString:searchTerm];
    //query.limit = 50;

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:self
 selector:@selector(callbackWithResult:error:)];

     }
```

If you need it here is the full .m file

```
#import "AllDataTableViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@implementation AllDataTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController 

@synthesize searchBar;
@synthesize searchController;
@synthesize searchResults;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        self.className = @"TruthIsData";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"truthIsName";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;

    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];
}


- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"truthIsName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User: %@", [object objectForKey:@"username"]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)callbackWithResult:(NSArray *)objects error:(NSError *)error
{
    if(!error) {
        [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
        [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:objects];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    }
}


- (void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"TruthIsData"];
    [query whereKey:@"truthIsName"  containsString:searchTerm];
    //query.limit = 50;

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callbackWithResult:error:)];

}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterResults:searchString];
    return YES;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        return self.objects.count;
    } else {
        return self.searchResults.count ;
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}


@end
```

Thanks!

After adding the line I get

```
TutorialBase[764:20074] Queried Objects: (
    "<TruthIsData:6ikJq0hhtc:(null)> {\n    truthIsName = g;\n}"
) ((null))
```

Comment: would you add `NSLog(@"Queried Objects: %@ (%@)", objects, [error localizedDescription]);` at the beginning of `callbackWithResult:` and report what you get when you search for `g`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about the flow in your class, but it seems to me that you are not using at all the results of the query (as stored in `self.searchResults`).

More precisely, you are not dealing with search results in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:`. I would expect something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

      if (tableView == self.tableView) {
          <actual implementation here>
      } else {
          <similar implementation but where you get the data from self.searchResults>
      }
}
```

(along the lines of what you do in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`)

Actually, what I would do is overriding the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

      if (tableView == self.tableView) {
          //-- this will call into PFQueryTable and then into tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:object:
          [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      } else {
          <similar implementation but where you get the data from self.searchResults>
      }
}
```

So that you do not go into PFQueryTableView for searchResults (which are displayed in a different table view altogether).

I am not sure that it is a good idea to have the same class act both as a delegate/datasource for `PFQueryTableView` and `UISearchDisplayController` -- your code would be definitely more readable if you have a specialised class for the latter's datasource. But that is just a suggestion.

EDIT:

This is how it could look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  if (tableView == self.tableView) {
      //-- this will call into PFQueryTable and then into tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:object:
      [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  } else {

    PFObject* object = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"truthIsName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User: %@", [object objectForKey:@"username"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What you said makes sense. I don't know how I would do the similar implementation though. Could you show me what that would be like?

Comment: thank you so much for your time. I am now getting a strange error and cannot find why even after doing much research. Sorry to ask you again but the error is +[AllDataTableViewController _needSetup]:unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1f83b0

Comment: this happens when i load that view controller (AllDataTableViewController)

Comment: the method _needSetup is being called on AllDataTableViewController, but it is not defined. you should add an exception breakpoint to see when exactly that method is called and by whom. (goggle Xcode exception breakpoint).